# What exactly maven does when a transitive dependency is excluded?

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin

Impact of exclusion in the context of jar packaging(simple/fat jar using shade plugin). What i mean here, how can it be verified by extracting the jar.

Answer (score 1):

When a dependency is excluded, it is removed from the dependency tree *at that point*. You can check this with `mvn dependency:tree`. It might still come in through other ways (e.g. as transitive dependency of some other dependency). You can check that with `mvn dependency:list`.

Comment: So, if its not coming via any other ways, pertaining .class should never be in the packaged jar?

Comment: The classes of an excluded dependency are not present in the fat jar (unless they come through some other way).